# Wampserver sql dump

Tags: wampserver

I know this has been asked many times before.  But I am getting a:

```
The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
```

First off I am using WanmpServer3.0.0 64 on a Win7 64 VM.
-I tried editing the php.ini file to give an absolute path to no avail
-made sure that the extension=phpmbstring.dll is uncommented

Another problem is that i noticed that whenever i load a php page it has fatal errors for my mysql commands.

When I use the wampmanager from the tray to open the php.ini file instead of through windows explorer I get:

```
Cannot find the C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin\php.ini file.  Do you want to create a new file?
```

So now I'm thinking something has gone drastically wrong and would like to uninstall/reinstall Wamp.  I attempt to use the mysql console to save my databases before deleting the wamp directory.  However when I run a mysqldump -all-databases > all_database.sql it just drops down to an empty line and nothing happens.

[mysql console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdj4z.png)

If I browse around in the C:\wamp64 directory i find the "data" directory within \bin\mysql where it seems all of my databases reside but not in readable form.

Is there anyway to save my databases??

BTW:  This whole setup was working fine previously, so I'm not sure what caused the crash and burn.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out.

I opened the php.ini file from the PHP bin folder and copied all of the contents into a new php.ini file to reside in the apache bin file.

Now everything works again.

I'm not sure this is how wampserver is supposed to work or what changed to start the problem but it's pseudo-resolved now.